# Misuse Attacks on Lattice Crypto

Tags: cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

I've been reading "Misuse Attacks on Post-Quantum Cryptosystems" (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/525). In what scenarios are the attacks described in the paper applicable? Is it specifically if a key is reused to generate more than one encapsulated key? Or is it more general? Does it apply to all 'unfailing' reconciliation mechanisms?

Comment: According to the abstract, at least one of the claimed attack indeed is quantum: "In the latter case, we assume quantum access to the decryption oracle."

Comment: The paper covers a classical KR-PCA attacks and two quantum KR-CCA attacks (GKZ and AJOP based). I'm curious about all of them, so I'll edit the title.